# importing a class from another python file issue

Tags: python

Hi I want to import a class from another file in python, everything works however the class I want to import receives a command line argument. After I import (which is successful) how would I supply that command line argument in the class? (side:note is this a superclass or something? idk what that means)

```
#class I'm importing
class trend: 

def __init__(self):
    self.user_name = sys.argv[1] #receives commandline argument

_______________________________________________________________

#class I want to use it in
class game: 

    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

    def do_something(self):
        import filenameforthetrendclass as TC
        game = TC.trend() #how do I bring in the commandline argument in here?
```

Comment: You would rewrite that class, because that is a very bad way to set an instance attribute.

Comment: @roippi yeah that was my plan b, im trying to learn good design patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use `sys.argv` anywhere but at the top-level (`main`, if you have one). That's something you should pass in.

First, re-write `Trend` to take `user_name` as a parameter to its constructor.

Quick example with just `Trend`:

```
class Trend(object):

    def __init__(self, user_name):
        self.user_name = user_name

trend = Trend(sys.argv[1])
```

Now integrating the whole concept:

```
import sys
from filenameforthetrendclass import Trend

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

    def do_something(self, user_name):
        a_trend = Trend(user_name)      # was originally 'game = '


def main():
    game = Game()
    game.do_something(sys.argv[1])
```

Notes:

- I'm using uppercase names for classes
- I'm *definitely* not having a class named `game` and then using `game` as a local variable somewhere.